# How can I execute Javascipt after rerendering a component?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, ajax

I have the following code:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="saveRecords" action="{!saveRecords}"   
                     reRender="recordsTable" oncomplete="saveComplete();"/>
```

However the code I execute in the saveComplete(); doesn't always execute after the rerender of the records table. Is there something I'm missing or an easy way to get the state?

Comment: did you look in your javascript console for any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this   :

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" onclick="saveRecords()" reRender="none"/>
<apex:actionFunction name="saveRecords" action="{!saveRecords}" reRender="recordsTable" oncomplete="saveComplete()"/>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you've done here MML? I am calling saveRecords() from a command button already

Comment: one of the way to solve the reRender issue while using apex:actionFunction with apex:commandButton. anything wrong here?